# How can I read text file with hashmap that contain three columns?

Tags: java

I want to write A Star Algorithm by java program and I want to read the distance from the Text file like this

```
    89  R A
    118 A T
    140 M S
    85  B U
```

As you see in my text file I have three columns but with this code that I wrote it will give me just two columns but I want to read all of my columns which is three columns as you see in above

```
List<String> halist = new ArrayList<String>();

File f = new File("mapfile.txt");

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);

BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

while ( (record=dis.readLine()) != null ) {
    Map<Integer, String> hamap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    String[] columns = record.split(" ");
    hamap.put(Integer.valueOf(columns[0]), columns[1]);

    for(Map.Entry<Integer,String> m :hamap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(m.getKey()+" "+m.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never use the third column

```
hamap.put(Integer.valueOf(columns[0]), columns[1] +" " + columns[2]);
```

Or you can use Lists of Lists:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> hamap = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();

String[] columns = record.split(" ");
List<String> otherColumns = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i=1; i < columns.length; i++) {
    otherColumns.add(columns[i]);
}

hamap.put(Integer.valueOf(columns[0]), otherColumns);

for(Map.Entry<Integer,List<String>> m :hamap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(m.getKey()+" "+m.getValue());
}
```

Comment: I did it but I want another way tell me if you know?

Comment: you can use lists of lists as suggested by the other answers

Comment: This error because java program tell me Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Map.Entry<Integer,List<String>> to Map.Entry<Integer,String>

Comment: i suggest you post another question with the a star issue

Comment: Idea: avoid expanding paths that are already expensive
                         Uniform cost + Greedy Search
 evaluation function: f(n) = g(n) + h(n) with:
  g(n) – cost so far to reach n
  h(n) – estimated cost to goal from n
  f(n) – estimated total cost of path through n to goal

Comment: This is another file contain Greedy A 366
B 0
C 160
D 242
E 161
F 178
G 77
H 151

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you're only putting 2 values into your hashmap.

```
hamap.put(Integer.valueOf(columns[0]), columns[1]);
```

Now there are 2 potential approaches here

IF your integer value is a key to the other 2 values, than instead of having a `Map<Integer, String>` , you should have a Map  Where `SomeObject` contains your 2 other strings.

IF the integer is NOT a key,

Then you're better off using a collection of collections(like a List of Arrays for example) to represent you lines, OR you can have a `SomeObject` representing all 3 values, and have a list of `SomeObject`

So in this approach

```
Class SomeObject
{
    int theInt;
    string firstString;
    string secondString;

    public SomeObject(/*maybe some params here*/)
    {
         // insert constructor here
    }
}
```

would represent your line-items, and you'd have a collection of those.

```
someList.Add(New SomeObject(Integer.valueOf(columns[0]), columns[1], columns[2]));
```