# Java <Integer, String, String, String> collection and operations on data from txt file

Tags: java, string, collections, integer

I've used information from this link, but I have a lot of problems with other things.
[How can I read text file with hashmap that contain three columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809645/how-can-i-read-text-file-with-hashmap-that-contain-three-columns)

I have .txt file which contains data like this:

```
1 WORD1 WORD11 WORD111

2 WORD2 WORD22 WORD222

3 WORD3 WORD33 WORD333
```

What I want to get:

- k = generated number from 1 to x (depends on rows in txt file - I can handle this)
- show k (as WORD1 or WORD2 or...) I mean: `System.out.println(1) -> OUTPUT: WORD1`
- after that read from keyboard "WORD11" and "WORD111" and if entered WORD11 and WORD111 is the same like word in file, return true.

I don't know how to operate on that data. Second point seems to be most difficult, but I don't event know what collection should I use (map, array, list etc). Any information would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple approach would be to define a class, that represents one row, like this:

```
public class Row {
    private String col1;
    private String col2;
    private String col3;

    // ... getter & setter
}
```

Then have a map using this class: `Map<Integer, Row> rows = new HashMap<Integer,Row>()`.

To improve the class, you could keep the columns flexible.

```
public class Row {
    private List<String> cols = new ArrayList<String>();

    // ... getter & setter etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make an object with the number, word1, word11 and word111 and when you read the data, you create this objects, in a collection or hashmap. when the user enters the word11, text, you only need to compare the literal with the member of your object.

Simple an object like Moritz Petersen suggests in his answer.